# Calculate $\mathbb{E}(W_t^k)$ for a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq0}$ using Itô's Lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Show by using Ito's Lemma, for $k \geq 2$ the following result hold.

$$E[W(t)^k] = \frac{1}{2} k(k-1)\int_0^t E[W(s)^{k-2}]ds$$

where $W(t) = N(0,t)$ is standard Brownian motion.

I think $E[W(t)^k]$ is an expectation over space,

$$E[W(t)^k] = \int_x x^k N(0,t) dx $$

How could I derive to the R.H.S. which contains a time integral? I am lacking a hint on this.

Comment: Perhaps, you can try integration by parts in
$$
  W_t^k = \int_0^t \mathrm dW_s^k
$$
a couple of times to decrease the degree of $W_s$ and then take an expectation.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how could I know the following operation is well defined? $$W^k_t = \int_0^t dW^k_t = \int_0^t k dW^{k-1}_t = \int_0^t k(k-1) dW^{k-2}_t =$$ I think $dW$ is different from $dx$ in the sense that $dW$ is differentiation of a random variable

Comment: val: A very healthy reaction, I must say! See @saz's answer.

Answer (score 14):

Let $f(x) := x^k$, then by Itô's formula

$$W_t^k = \int_0^t k \cdot W_s^{k-1} \, dW_s + \frac{1}{2} k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \int_0^t W_s^{k-2} \, ds$$

Since $(t,\omega) \mapsto \left(\int_0^t k \cdot W_s^{k-1} \, dW_s \right)(\omega)$ is a martingale, we have $$\mathbb{E}(W_t^k) = 0+ \frac{1}{2} k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t W_s^{k-2} \, ds \right) = \frac{1}{2} k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(W_s^{k-2}) \, ds$$

Comment: What is up with martingales? Isn't it more of the zero mean property?

Comment: @BCLC The stochastic integral is a martingale and therefore it has in particular mean $0$.

Comment: Huh? Why does martingale => zero mean? I just thought it meant same mean through out.

Comment: saz, actually isn't the fact that the stochastic integral has zero mean used in showing that the stochastic integral is a martingale?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, but in this particular case we know that for $t=0$ the process equals $0$. (If $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, $M_0=0$, then $\mathbb{E}M_t=0$ for all $t \geq 0$.)

Comment: And no, it is not used in showing that the stochastic integral is a martingale; at least not in the proof I know.

Comment: Uhuh, my mistake. I just browsed the martingale proof quickly hahaha. Wait so the expected value of an Ito integral (of functions of those properties whose collective name we were not given) ISN'T necessarily zero?

Comment: @BCLC No, the expected value of an Itô integral *is* zero. Note that the stochastic integral $$M_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$$ is a martingale and $M_0=0$. Therefore, it follows that $$\mathbb{E}M_t = \mathbb{E}M_0=0.$$

Comment: ......................................................................................................................................................................................................so was my stochastic calculus professor being inelegant when e gave us a proof of zero mean property w/o using the martingale property? :O

Comment: @BCLC I don't know. At least if one has already shown that the stochastic integral is a martingale, then the zero mean property is an obvious consequence.

Comment: Okay I'll ask h then. Thanks saz ^_^

Comment: @Emmy Please see my answer in the other question where you asked... it's exactly the same reasoning.

Comment: @Emmy Yes, you are.